# How do I convert <%= link_to "Upgrade", :settings, :class => "button" %> to a block in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to produce this link:

```
<a href="/settings" class="button"><span class="magnifier icon"></span>Search</a>
```

So as far as I understand it I have to convert

```
<%= link_to "Upgrade", :settings, :class => "button" %>
```

To a block, but when I do this:

```
<%= link_to "Upgrade", :settings, :class => "button" do %>
   <span class="magnifier icon">Search</span>
<% end %>
```

It gives me the following error:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for :settings:Symbol
```

However, when I do: `<%= link_to "Upgrade", :settings, :class => "button" %>` it works perfectly.

How do I convert this to a block ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using a block, the first argument no longer contains the link content. The block is responsible for that. Therefore, it thinks that `"Upgrade"` is your link's destination and `:settings` is your options hash.

Remove `"Upgrade"` and put it in the block.