# undefined method `stringify_keys' (ROR)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to correct write this record? When I write the following code, which you can see in this post I have received following mistake: undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/plant/index":String

**Html code**

```
<li class="new_button">
<%= link_to "Plants", plant_path, :class=>"greens" do %>
<span></span>
<% end %>
</li>
```

**I need** (just with link_to)

```
<li class="new_button"><a href="#" class="greens">Plants<span></span></a></li>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307032/how-do-i-convert-link-to-upgrade-settings-class-button-to-a-bl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass block into `link_to`, first argument is responsible for evaluating proper link `href` and second argument is assumed options. In your example, second argument is returned value of `plant_path`, which is `String` instance, but Rails want to evaluate it as `Hash`. What you should do is:

```
<%= link_to plant_path, class: 'greens' do %>
  Plants<span></span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: No, no! See my update post. Plants should't lie in span.

Comment: @CaT check my updated answer (BTW, it's quite easy to figure out how to change `<span>Plants</span>` into `Plants<span></span>`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= link_to plant_path, :class=>"greens" do %>
 <span><%= "Plants" %></span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I need span be empty. <span></span>

Comment: just this `<%= link_to "Plants", plant_path, :class=>"greens" %>` or place `<%= "Plants" %>` just before `span` tag

Comment: Plants -> name of link, but in span lied another object.

Comment: my previous comment had your answer @CaT